# radeon mobility hd 6620g hdmi sound output not working

Tags: 12.10, radeon

Output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek [Mobility Radeon HD 6620G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

---

I did a standard install of Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. using X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(open source tested)
I get the video image just fine through hdmi to the TV, but the audio fails to come through when I switch the sound to the HDMI hardware. 
I have tried the "fglrx-legacy" fix, but this is an "ATI 6620G" and that fix is mainly for 4000 series and older, so it came without success. 
***By the way, this was not an issue with Ubuntu 12.04 and the Catalyst Control Center***

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx fglrx-update

sudo apt-get install fglrx

sudo aticonfig --initial

sudo shutdown now -rf
```

now it runs like a champ